# Creating .Net Core Global Tool with sqlite cannot load SQLite.Interop

Tags: sqlite, f#, .net-core, nuget

I'm writing a .Net Core global tool which accesses a SQLite database. I'm using [SQLProvider](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider) for my ORM needs with `System.Data.SQLite.Core`. Within the SQLProvider docs, it states something about having to copy the SQLite.Interop.dll to the output path, and I believe I've done that correctly as the program executes as it should from Visual Studio, as well as using Fake to build the project in Release mode and run the resulting .dll directly with dotnet.

However, when I try to package it as a NuGet file, when I try to run the program it fails with `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies` and I can't figure out if the copying of the SQLite.Interop.dll is correct, or there's some other problems. This error only occurs if I try to run the installed global tool, and not if I run the Release mode binary via dotnet

edit from comments:

The SQLite.Interop.dll is not included inside the NuGet package. I'm creating the NuGet via fake 5 which calls `DotNet.pack`. How would I tell that step to include the dll?

The pack step currently looks like this

```
Target.create "Pack" (fun _ ->
DotNet.pack (fun packOptions ->
    { packOptions with 
        Configuration = DotNet.BuildConfiguration.Release
        NoBuild = true
        VersionSuffix = Some "1.0.1-preview8"
        OutputPath = Some outputDirectory }
) "./src/WhereInTheWorld/WhereInTheWorld.fsproj"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `SQLite.Interop.dll` getting into your NuGet file? If not, then you'll need to tweak your build somehow to make sure it gets into the file. Since NuGet files are standard Zip files with a different extension, you should be able to just open the NuGet file in any zip tool and check that its contents include SQLite.Interop.dll.

Comment: It is not inside the NuGet file. Maybe that means my question then becomes how do I include the dll with dotnet pack executed by fake? Updated the question btw

Comment: Did you add the `PackAsTool` tag? Check [Nate McMaster's article](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/05/12/dotnet-global-tools/), it explains what's going on under the hood. Try creating the tool from the CLI *first*, so you don't have to wonder about Fake's syntax and .... quirks. Check the [Publish output into pack](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/05/12/dotnet-global-tools/#publish-output-into-pack). As the article explains, `dotnet pack` by itself only packs the output of `dotnet build` command. Adding the `PackAsTool` tag packs the output of `dotnet publish`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after the comment my rmunn. It had to do with getting the interop dll into the final nuget file. I added this to my .fsproj file

```
<Content Include="../../packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/build/net46/**/*">
    <Pack>true</Pack>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```